# Integrate $\frac{5x^3 +2}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{5x^3+2}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Sad to say this has really stumped me and nothing I have tried has worked.

I used Wolfram Alpha to find that the answer is simply $2x\sqrt{x^3+1}$ but it says the method is unavailable and I have no idea which method to use. Hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you used $u$ substitution?

Comment: Yes but none that I tried worked

Comment: Hint:  Take a look at my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358452/evaluate-int-0-1-left-x-5-x-4-x-2-right/498977#498977

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observe that 
$$\int \frac{5x^3+2}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}dx=\int \frac{x(5x^3+2)}{x\sqrt{x^3+1}}dx=\int \frac{5x^4+2x}{\sqrt{x^5+x^2}}dx$$
and make the $u$-substitution $u=x^5+x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, that's so simple! How does one spot tricks like these?

Comment: @Oliver That's the same trick for computing $\int \sec x$.

Comment: How do you figure out which factor to multiply the top & bottom by?

Comment: @Oliver Essentially I wanted to do the $u$-substitution $u=x^3+2$ but both polynomials have the same degree. Multiplying for $x$ increases the degree by one on top and two on the bottom because of the square root. But I wasn't expecting that would solve it directly.

Comment: Simple and profound! Nice. :) +1